# How to prevent flickering placeholder content before async response

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mobile, user-experience

What’s your recommendation on showing views with async data? I have one view which briefly shows placeholder text until actual data is available to replace it. What is the UX best practice in this case?

I have the target profile view showing a loading mask and making the async call based on a passed user id. I also have a caching mechanism in place but the first call will always suffer.

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Don't show any placeholder text. Leave it blank. After data is retrieved add placeholder text for any missing attributes if required

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what asynchronous data you're talking about, because the preceding scene had the name and image you wanted to show in this destination scene. So, rather than re-retrieving this data asynchronously, pass the necessary information to the next scene (e.g. in `prepareForSegue` pass the name and image) and have `viewDidLoad` populate that `image` of the image view and the `text` of the label. That way, the destination scene will appear with the correct data without any flickering.

But let's imagine that you really need to retrieve data asynchronously (e.g. the "following", "followers" and "checkins"), you can either have the placeholders be blank so the asynchronous retrieval is less jarring. Or, if that destination scene is going to change radically after the data is retrieved asynchronously, you might want to present a "HUD" (e.g. blur the entire view with a `UIEffectView` and place a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of that), so the user can clearly see (a) the app is still alive; but (b) retrieving data; and when the data comes in, fill in the view and then remove the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and the `UIEffectView`.

However you do this, I'd suggest you test your UI while the app is running with the network link conditioner simulating a very poor connection. It's easy to design an app in best-case-scenario environment (e.g. great wifi connection) and forget that users may be using it in suboptimal environment (e.g. 2G Edge network with poor reception).